# Area within $x=0$ $y=x$ and $e^{-x}$

Tags: integration

Is there a way to find the area within $x=0$ $y=x$ and $e^{-x}$ without solving numerically $e^{-x}=x$ ?

Comment: Within $y=0$ and $y=x$ or within $y=0$ and $y=e^{-x}$ ? Or something else ? This is a bit unclear :3

Comment: So you are looking for the area between $y=x$ and $y=e^{-x}$ from $0$ to ?

Comment: yes starting from x=0

Comment: That's $\int_0^x t\ dt - \int_0^x e^{-t}dt$, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find:
$$\int_0^\alpha(e^{-x}-x)dx\quad\text{where }e^{-\alpha}=\alpha$$
I think there's no other way:
$$\int_0^\alpha(e^{-x}-x)dx=(-e^{-x}-x^2/2)_0^\alpha=1-e^{-\alpha}-\alpha^2/2=1-\alpha-\alpha^2/2$$

Comment: @Parhs yup I also didn't notice

Comment: sorry it was correct it seems it should be +1 .